# In 10. power / calculation / Power calculations

Tags: objective-c, xcode, exponentiation

i am working on an apps for calculating fuel...

i need to know how i can power a number in 10?

the Excel code is "10^1.5"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you mean in XCode, you have to `#include <math.h>` and then you can use `pow`:

```
double res=pow(10, 1.5);
```

Comment: Ha, I thought he was talking about Excel.  You are probably right. +1