# Objective-C - calculating x ^ y

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to raise a double value by power of 12?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816055/how-to-raise-a-double-value-by-power-of-12)
>   [In 10. power / calculation / Power calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810108/in-10-power-calculation-power-calculations)

In object C for the iPhone, how would I calculate x^y?  Getting the values by popping a stack

Comment: are you talking about power or xor?

Comment: power, sorry.  nhahtdh's answer did it for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should to `#include <math.h>` and then you can use

```
double res=pow(10, 1.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pow(x,y).

It returns a **double** value.

To cast to an integer,
myPowerNum = (int)pow((double)x, (double)y);